# Why params are not changing when the ReactJS webapp is switching between two similar routes with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route:

```
<Route name="note" path="/note/:noteId" handler={Note}/>
```

When i'm going in my webapp from page `/note/123` to `/note/456` the params are not changing:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        console.log('this.props.params.noteId, prevProps.params.noteId', this.props.params.noteId, prevProps.params.noteId)
}
```

`this.props.params.noteId` and `prevProps.params.noteId` are equal

Comment: have you tried using `componentWillRecieveProps` ??